# KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented with documented versions

Tags: java, gradle, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am in the process of upgrading a ton of dependencies to get rid of any known vulnerabilities. One of which was an old zookeeper version as a transient dependency.

So using gradle I substituted the version with the latest zookeeper

```
substitute module('org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper') with module('org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.6.1')
```

However of course it wasn't that easy and I got this error upon startup

```
2020-05-08 12:03:53,509 [ERROR] (main) org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl    - Could not register instances - will try again later
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$UnimplementedException: KeeperErrorCode = Unimplemented for /applications/...
```

From what I can tell this is because curator(also a transient dependency) is not compatible with that zookeeper version.

After looking here http://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility.html I take it that curator is not compatible with zk `3.6.x`

and so I settled on this which I assumed would work

```
substitute module('org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper') with module('org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.5.7')
substitute module('org.apache.curator:curator-recipes') with module('org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:4.3.0')
substitute module('org.apache.curator:curator-x-discovery') with module('org.apache.curator:curator-x-discovery:4.3.0')
```

But it doesn't. I get the same `UnimplementedException` as before even though they should be compatible?

So am I missing something obvious as to why it won't work?

For the sake of it I've run this for both zookeeper and cura

```
./gradlew -q dependencyInsight -p ./ --dependency zookeeper
```

and all the versions are correct (4.3.0 for everything cura related and 3.5.7 for zk)

**UPDATE:**

So I am not sure if this is just chasing smoke or not, but I found some errors in regards to `dropwizard`
I was running with this dependency

```
io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:2.0.9
```

that will give the UnimplementedException previously mentioned.
however I saw that curator was also implementing dropwizard but on a different version:
https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/apache-curator-4.3.0/pom.xml#L88
So I downgraded my dropwizard to 1.3.7 which gave me some other errors:

```
2020-05-11 12:46:39,776 [WARN ] (main) org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.ROOT    - unavailable
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceFinderBinder
```

and after investigating it looks like dropwizard is using an older version of jersey, so I upgraded that

```
substitute module('org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services') with module('org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-metainf-services:2.30')
substitute module('org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation') with module('org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:2.30')
```

and now I am back to the original UnimplementedException problem.
So not sure if any of that was relevant or not

I don't really feel like the exception aligns with it, but could the issue be my jersey version?
https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/apache-curator-4.3.0/pom.xml#L72
I am using jersey `2.30`

Comment: I don't know much about Gradle so I can't help there. But, we should have a 3.6.x compatible version of Curator out by end of May to early June. FYI

Comment: fair, but I tried downgrading to zk 3.5.7 and curator 4.3.0. from what I understand these should be compatible, right? so why am I seeing the same UnimplementedException?

Comment: I don't know Gradle well enough to answer but you can see from the source that Curator 4.3.0 was built against ZK 3.5.7: https://github.com/apache/curator/blob/apache-curator-4.3.0/pom.xml#L63

Comment: Curator does not use Dropwizard. You're seeing some declarations for it but they are old. Curator does not have any dependency on Dropwizard.

Comment: Gradle has a dependency tree function I'm sure. Use it to see where the conflicts are. Maybe sure everything is using the same versions or exclude deps that you don't have control over.

Comment: It does have a dependency tree function. But when I am using substitute module in the way that I am it is replacing all versions with the one I am specifying. So there at least aren't any conflicts in terms of different versions

Comment: Post an example and I'll take a look.